# The sumo rerouter cannot find the route

Tags: sumo

I use Siouxfalls network for simulation, and in run-time, I want to close the edge from node 19 to node 17 (which is named 19to17).
To do this, I use additional file like this:

```
<rerouter id="rerout1" edges="19to17" probability="1.0">
   <interval begin="300" end="1500">
       <closingReroute id="19to17"/>
   </interval>
</rerouter>
```

This rerouter does not make any change in vehicle movements and all vehicles used to pass 19to17, again pass it, but this time with just a warning.
Next time, I add the following line after closingRoute to show the other routes that they can choose:

```
<destProbReroute id="19to15;15to10;10to17"/>
```

I have the warning for ';', so I separet it in three lines:

```
 <destProbReroute id="19to15"/> 
 <destProbReroute id="15to10"/>
 <destProbReroute id="10to17"/>
```

And again no change in the output results!

So, How does the rerouter work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (closing) rerouter needs two sets of edges one which gets closed and one where the vehicles get notified of the closure. It is not a good idea to let the notification edge be a closed edge because it is too late to find a new route if you are already on the closed edge.

The notification edges are the ones in the `edges` attribute of the rerouter while the closed edge is the `id` in the `closingReroute` part. The first one should be upstream of the second.

Comment: Tones of thanks. I change the additional file to   <rerouter id="rerout1" edges="15to19 20to19">
   <interval begin="300" end="1500">
       <closingReroute id="19to17" disallow="all"/>   
   </interval>
</rerouter>,   Two problems strikes my mind: 1. I do not introduce any alternative routes.   I know it shoud be sth like <destProbReroute id="rerout2"/>  , but where should I introduce rerout2?  (rerout2 to is:  19to15 15to10 10to17).  And also another question is, where should I call the additional file? In the "duarcfg_file.trips2routes.duarcfg" or "config_file.sumocfg"?

Comment: Thanks, Solved up to this step. The next problem is that vehicles just stop at the intersection and do not make a reroute. I mean there is another way (which is a longer path, such as 19to15, 15to10, 10to17), but they just stop at the intersection. that would be great if you can help

Comment: It is probably better to continue this on the mailing list where you can attach your input files for inspection.